# apt-get and php5 on Ubuntu - Impossible to install cause of dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, dependencies, php5

I am trying to run

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

And getting this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.4.17-1~dotdeb.1) but it is not going to be installed or
             libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.4.17-1~dotdeb.1) but it is not going to be installed or
             php5-cgi (>= 5.4.17-1~dotdeb.1) but it is not going to be installed or
             php5-fpm (>= 5.4.17-1~dotdeb.1) but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: php5-common (>= 5.4.17-1~dotdeb.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? You have not pasted the full `apt-get` output; there might be interesting parts left out. Have you tried just running `sudo apt-get update` and then retrying the installation? It might just be a transitional problem that will go away in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output seems to indicate you use additional repositories.  So one alternative would be to restrict yourself to the official repositories, so as to avoid conflict.  Or it could be your alternative repository is set to a different version of Ubuntu (or even Debian), case in which you would want to edit your /etc/apt/sources.list to fix it (or use your favourite GUI to that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you don't get any errors then try the install again, if that doesn't fix it try installing the dependencies manually.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-common
```